# open source .Net wiki?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, wiki

Could anyone recommend me a good open source .Net based wiki project? Better with successful deployment and user experience, and have a good community to support. :-)

Thanks!

regards,
George

Comment: It is related to programming- I'd imagine almost all decent programming teams have a wiki.

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault.com

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here either, but even if it did - it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883426/looking-for-open-source-net-wiki-blog
or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177293/what-is-the-best-asp-net-wiki-out-there
or really, a pile of others... seems like every few weeks there's another "recommend a wiki" question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Screwturn wiki- http://www.screwturn.eu/ is what I currently use successfully.

Comment: We use ScrewTurn too - works fine with Active Directory auth on our intranet, and uses the filesystem so doesn't need a database.

Comment: Screwturn has been discontinued now

Answer (score 3):

[DekiWiki](http://www.mindtouch.com/)

Runs even on Mono. The [MonoDevelop site](http://monodevelop.com/) runs on it.

Answer (score 2):

**[Roadkill .NET Wiki engine:](https://github.com/roadkillwiki/roadkill)**

- Free, open source (Ms-PL)
- Wizard-based installer
- Supports Creole, Markdown and Media Wiki syntax
- Both database and Active Directory security by default
- Very easy to theme: comes with a mediawiki theme by default
- Comes with a screw-turn importer
- Also works with Mono on Ubuntu

And its technologies:

- .NET 4 (sorry 2.0/3.5 people!)
- LightSpeed ORM - works with SQL Server, Sqlite, Postgres, MySQL, MongoDB
- ASP.NET MVC 3/razor
- JQuery
- Lucene.net

[image: Logo]

Comment: @dirt I'll use your quote on the homepage ;) - `Sounds awesome - Dirt`